# How can I prevent the cross origin error with livewire components?

Tags: dns, cors, laravel-livewire

I have a laravel 8.75 project using livewire 2.12.

When I access my site with https://www.example.com I have a cross site origin error :

`Access to fetch at 'https://example.com/livewire/message/compatibility-form' from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

And when I access with https://example.com I have no error it works fine.

I understand that I have two solutions :

1- Configure cors to include these two domains https://example.com and https://www.example.com

2- Make a redirection from https://www.example.com to https://example.com

I use fruitcake/laravel-cors package to deal cors policy and I tried to configure like this the config/cors.php :

```php
    'allowed_origins' => ['https://www.example.com', 'https://example.com],
```

After changing that I run php artisan config:clear but it doesn't work.

I already have a dns registration on gandi.net for www, type A to the ip address of the server; and a web redirection from https://www.example.com and http://www.example.com to https://example.com

I also check the .htaccess file and it seems that the redirection is configured there too :

```php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Do you have any idea on what I have to change or add to prevent these errors?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem by changing the livewire configuration :

```php
'asset_url' => (request()->isSecure() ? 'https://' : 'http://') . request()->getHttpHost(),
```

This allows the livewire components to function correctly regardless of the URL.